# Phone gap 3.4 : how to navigate to native map on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I developing mobile app by using Phonegap 3.4 and I would like to link my app to open a native map in the phone.

So I wrote down javascript like

```
function openNativeApp(latlng){
    window.open('http://maps.apple.com/?q='+latlng, '_system');
}
```

but when i test on the app, it just open new webView and show google map in mobile version.

By this code I have done well on Phonegap 2.9 but when I try in Phonegap 3.4, it doesn't.

Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try This code, I use in my mobile app and it works fine for me.

```
<a onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('http://maps.apple.com/?q='+latlng, '_system', { openExternal:true });">Link</a>
```